# Conditional override of global variable, locally not availlable

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, overriding, conditional-statements

Why is this not possible?

```
CONSTANT = 1
def main():
    if False:
        CONSTANT = 0
    print(CONSTANT)
main()
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'CONSTANT' referenced before assignment
```

Explicit assignment doesn't change anything:

```
CONSTANT = 1
def main():
    CONSTANT = CONSTANT
    if False:
        CONSTANT = 0
    print(CONSTANT)
main()
```

Only changing the name does the job:

```
CONSTANT = 1
def main():
    constant = CONSTANT
    if False:
        constant = 0
    print(constant)
main()
```

That's kind of annoying, can I somehow avoid that behaviour?

Comment: `if False` will never run.  Why is it in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `CONSTANT` as a global.

```
CONSTANT = 1
def main():
    global CONSTANT
    print(CONSTANT)
    CONSTANT = 0
    print(CONSTANT)
main()
```

Comment: well, that's it ;)
Thanks!